# HT Access in IE using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, .htaccess

I need to make a rest api call to a website say xyx.com.

It has a usual authentication and i have implemented it in jquery.

say

```
return $.getJSON('xyx.com/restapi/login?userid=aaa&pass=qqq'+"&xslt=json.xsl&
callback=?",function(jsonResult)
{
    if(jsonResult.response.status   ==  'success')
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
},"jsonp");
```

the above is working fine.

Now HT Access is provided to the above site xyx.com

I replaced the URL used in the above getJSON as follows

```
http://msf:sks1l*@xyx.com/restapi/login?userid=aaa&pass=qqq
```

where msf and sks11* are the HT Access credentials.

The above is working fine in FF but not in IE.

Any possible solutions or workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is just a shorthand for a specific kind of `$.ajax()` call. The jQuery docs show the details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. `$.getJSON` is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

And looking at the `$.ajax()` documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ it says:

> If the server performs HTTP authentication before providing a
>   response, the user name and password pair can be sent via the username
>   and password options.

So just use the `$.ajax()` form and pass a username and password, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://xyx.com/restapi/login?userid=aaa&pass=qqq",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(jsonResult) {
      /* your success code */
  },
  username: 'msf',
  password: ':sks1l*@'
});
```

Comment: Thats great. Thanks Ben I will try it.

Comment: This works perfect in Firefox. But fails in IE. As I have mentioned in the question the URL "http://msf:sks1l*@xyx.com/restapi/login?userid=aaa&pass=qqq" is working in FF but not in IE. I presume IE is not picking the HT Access username and password and it is throwing a dialog box for providing the HT Access username and password.

Comment: Not working in Firefox also. Getting following error "NetworkError: 401 Authorization Required - http:\\msft.com/restapi/vc/authentication/sessions/login?user.login=admin&user.password=come01&xslt=json.xsl&callback=jQuery17103062594674032523_1327929663010&_=1327929689677" followed by a dialog box to provide the HT credentials.